# Polya's Urn - probability of taking $k$ white balls in the first $n$ extractions

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

An urn contains $p$ black balls and $b$ white balls. A ball is taken from the urn and then the same ball is added back to the urn together with another ball of same color. This process is repeated indefinitely. Let $B_{n,k}$ be the event in which exactly $k$ white balls are taken in the first $n$ extractions. Show that:

$$ 
P(B_{n,k}) = \frac{{{b+k-1}\choose{b-1}} {{p+n-k-1}\choose{p-1}}}{{p+b+n-1}\choose{n}}
$$

Hint: Show by induction on $n$, for all $p$ and $b$.

---

I'm completely stuck with this problem!

Can't even get the base case for induction where $n = 1$, that would be taking $k$ white balls with $1$ extraction. Why would that be $\frac{{{b+k-1}\choose{b-1}} {{p-k}\choose{p-1}}}{p+b}$?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please write $P(B_{n, k})~$ as $ ~ = \displaystyle \frac{{{b+k-1}\choose{k}} {{p+n-k-1}\choose{n-k}}}{{p+b+n-1}\choose{n}}$. Now do you see for $n = 1$, why that is true?

Comment: @MathLover, as I mentioned, no... That'd be $\frac{{{b+k-1}\choose{b-1}} {{p-k}\choose{p-1}}}{p+b}$, and I still don't get why this is the probability for the $n=1$ case.

Comment: when $n = 1, k = 0$ or $k = 1$. Try both cases.

Comment: But why? If $n = 1$ then we're looking for taking in $n=1$ extraction $k$ white balls... Why should $0 \leq k \leq n$ ?

Comment: because the question says _same ball is added back to the urn together with another ball of same color_

Comment: so in $n$ extractions, you would have added $n$ balls and $k$ of them white. $k$ must be equal to less than $n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I can see why the base case holds.

Comment: @MathLover can you help with the induction hypothesis?

Comment: If it is true for $n, k$, you should be able to show it is true for $n + 1, k$ and $n + 1, k +1$. If you get stuck, post your attempt and I will help